# Is it possible to get full path for broken data source to repair broken data link?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

This question links back to an old question of mine: [Convert shapefiles in nested folder to geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82109/convert-shapefiles-in-nested-folder-to-geodatabase)

I am attempting to find a **permanent** solution to fixing the broken maps, and in such a way that they can easily be fixed if the maps documents get broken again.

As stated previously, I have hundreds of map documents all with broken data sources. It is not feasible to use findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths because the data is in a multitude of nested folders, not kept in one folder or geodatabase.

To complicate things further, many of the shapefiles used have the same name, but are located in a different folders.

arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources returns a list of the names of the layers that have a broken data source in the map document, but only the name. Within the map document, if I click on the Source tab of the Layer Properties it shows the 'location' of where the data should be.

I have a copy of all the GIS data from the old computer, so ideally I would be able to do something like OldDataSource.replace ('n:/', 'c:/users/athom/oldGIScomputer/')

Is it possible to use python to get the full 'location' + 'name' of the data in a broken data source?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your question:

> Is it possible to use python to get the full 'location' + 'name' of
>   the data in a broken data source?

This code should do it - just substitute in the full path and name for your MXD

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\test.mxd")
brkLayerList = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)
for lyr in brkLayerList:
    print lyr.dataSource
```

As an aside, you said:

> arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources returns a list of the **names of the
>   layers** that have a broken data source

but what arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources actually returns is a list of the **layer objects** that have a broken data source